# Convert Floating point double to non floating point string

Tags: java, floating-point

I have the following number:

`1.0645208E10`, which is in my case a double value. I would like to convert it into `106.45`.

Any recommendation how to get `106.45`?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: java.text.DecimalFormat (beware of the Locale though).

Comment: Do you want to change the double value, or do you only want to output the number (convert it into a string)? In the latter case, use the `format` method of the `String` class or `System.out.printf`.

Comment: 1.064..E10 is much bigger than 106.45, is this correct? Do you want to divide the number by 10^8 before conversion?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
    double bigDouble = 1.0645208E10;
    String strDouble = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", bigDouble/100000000);
    System.out.println(strDouble);
```

It will give you `106.45`

But be aware of the fact that the output has nothing to do with the original value!! Is one hundred million times smaller...

Answer (score 1):

> Any recommendation how to get 106.45?

If you want to get only output then you can do following.

```
Double d = 1.0645208E10;
String s = d.toString().replace(".", "");//Converts into string and removes dot (.)
String s1 = s.substring(0, 5);//it gets only first 5 characters 
String s2 = s1.substring(0, 3) + "." + s1.substring(3, 5);//it adds decimal point after first 3 character
System.out.println("Expected Output: " + s2);
```